# Need to test that a handler prop is called by a composite React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I would like to test that a `Select` component within my component calls my `onChange` and `onBlur` handlers correctly. I am using `jest` as my testing framework and `enzyme` for rendering my component for testing.

**Component**

```
import {Select} from 'antd'

function MyComponent (props) {
  const { onChange, onBlur, value, ...rest} = props
  return (<Select 
   {...rest} 
   value={value} 
   onChange={onChange} 
   onBlur={onBlur}
  />)
}
```

**Test**

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('calls the onChange if the value of select changes', () => {
        const onChange = jest.fn()
    const options = {
      enumOptions: [
        {
          label: 'Foo',
          value: 'foo'
        },
        {
          label: 'Bar',
          value: 'bar'
        }
      ]
    }

    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent options={options} onChange={onChange} />)
    const select = wrapper.find('select')
    select.simulate('change')

    expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalled()

  })
})
```

**Problem/Question**

The problem is that the `Select` component does not render a `select` element, so attempting to grab the `select` element and `simulate` an event on it causes an issue:

```
Method “simulate” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.

  at ReactWrapper.single (node_modules/enzyme/build/ReactWrapper.js:1419:17)
  at ReactWrapper.simulate (node_modules/enzyme/build/ReactWrapper.js:769:14)
  at Object.it (src/form-schema/widgets/Select/index.spec.js:172:12)
      at Promise (<anonymous>)
  at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:42:16)
      at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
```

How can I ensure that the `onChange` event is called on the component without having to `simulate` it.

**Alternate Approach**

1. `setProps` on `Select` to force change.

I would like to pass props to a nested component within my component using `enzyme` I found that `setProps` from `enzyme` is only supported on the root component when I tried to do this:

**Error**

```
ShallowWrapper::setProps() can only be called on the root

  at ShallowWrapper.setProps (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:339:17)
  at Object.it (src/form-schema/widgets/Select/index.spec.js:150:12)
      at Promise (<anonymous>)
  at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:42:16)
      at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
```

2. setProps on top level component twice:

Pass a `value` prop, pass another `value` prop down immediately thereafter to induce a change:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Select options={options} onChange={onChange} />)
const select = wrapper.find(AntdSelect)
wrapper.setProps({value: 'bar'})
wrapper.setProps({value: 'foo'})
```

**Error**

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected mock function to have been called.

  at Object.it (src/form-schema/widgets/Select/index.spec.js:153:22)
      at Promise (<anonymous>)
  at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:42:16)
      at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I would suggest you to write test cases for different components differently. Currently, you are doing it for MyComponent. So, dont write test cases for Select component in this suite. Make a different suite for Select. And you can use .instance() method of enzyme to generate that function.
2. If suppose the Select component you are importing is from a third party library then you'll have to check the elements inside that component. In order to simulate select, you might have to first simulate a keyDown event and then find the 'li' element in that component and then simulate click in that 'li'. Depends on the library you are using.

3.Here, you are only mocking the function. You have to setup a spy in order to test the function has been called or not. Check 'sinon'. Its been used with enzyme.

```
describe('Select', () => {
  it('calls the onChange if the value of select changes', () => {
    const onChange = jest.fn();
    onChange= sinon.spy();
    const wrapper = mount(<Select options={options} onChange={onChange} 
     />)
    wrapper.simulate('change')
    expect(onChange.called).toEqual(true);
         });
       })



  describe('MyComponent', () => {
    it('check select component exists', () => {
        const onChange = jest.fn()
      const options = {
       enumOptions: [
        {
          label: 'Foo',
          value: 'foo'
        },
        {
          label: 'Bar',
          value: 'bar'
        }
      ]
     }

    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent options={options} onChange=
     {onChange} />)
     const select = wrapper.find('select')
     select.length.toEqual('1');

   });
  })
```

This is if you are not using Select component from a third party library.